# PHP echo in javascript not displayed in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeypress="handleEvent(event)" name="FirstName" style="position: absolute; left: 50px;">
<script>
        function handleEvent(e){
           if(e.keyCode === 13){
                <?php 
                echo "hello";
                ?>
            }
        } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the PHP code in function and put alert("something") it works fine. But when I put an echo in PHP in function, "hello" is not displayed.
Please help me, struggling from 2 days.

Comment: `echo` is not a javascript function

Comment: I don't doubt that you were struggling, but judging by your skill level here I think you need to spend at least a couple months doing tutorials on both JS and PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP executes at runtime, your code creates something like this:

```
function handleEvent(e){
           if(e.keyCode === 13){
                hello
            }
        }
```

echo is a php function which simple prints eveything inside "" into the markup. So just print with php what you else would write by hand:

```
function handleEvent(e){
           if(e.keyCode === 13){
                <?php 
                echo "alert(\"hello\");";
                ?>
            }
        }
```

`echo "alert(\"hello\");";` tells php to print `alert("hello");`. The `\"` makes sure echo prints the `"` character itself (because the string that echo needs to print is also written in `"`, so you need to escape additional ones, alternatively write `echo 'alert("hello");';`)

Comment: It displays an alert, but I want it to be displayed in page

Comment: what do you mean by that? please go read some book what javascript does, what php does and what html does...